# How to dynamically order the implementation list of a interface with default value in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, factory-pattern

I have an interface which extends `java.util.function.Function`, there are 2 further implementation of the interface lets say class A, B which implements the interface Base;

```java
interface Base extends Function<Object, Object> {

  @Override
  default Object apply(Object object) {
    return object;     // simply do nothing
  }

  default boolean accept(String str) {
    return true;     // for choosing the right instance
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
class A implements Base {

  String validationString = "some-random-string";

  @Override
  public Object apply(Object object) {
    // update the object ....
    return object;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(String str) {
    return str.equals(validationString);
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
class B implements Base {

  String validationString = "some-random-string-2";

  @Override
  public Object apply(Object object) {
    // update the object ....
    return object;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(String str) {
    return str.equals(validationString);
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SomeService {

  List<Base> baseList;

  public void callingClass(String str) {

    // in below 
    // I want to order it in such a way that 
    // if str matches A.validationString then give back A's instance
    // else if str matches B.validationString then give back B's instance
    // else return Base's instance
    Base base = baseList.stream()
        .filter(baseImpl -> baseImpl.accept(str))
        .findFirst().orElseThrow();

  }
}
```

So, what I am trying to achieve, if there is any way from which I don't have to manually create a Factory Class (Factory Pattern) and dynamically Filter the instance A, B using accept() and if none find then return instance of Base (as default).

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining @k314159 and @atish.s solution and improving on that:

Expose the DefaultBase class as another bean, but add @Order annotation to put it last in list

```
@Component
@Order(Precedence.LAST)
class DefaultBase implements Base {
    default accepts(Object obj){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then changing the Service method to this:

```
public Base callingClass(String str) { 
    return baseList.stream()
        .filter(baseImpl -> baseImpl.accept(str))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();
}
```

Comment: What is the import for Precedence.LAST?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html), it looks like it should be `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`. Also, `default accepts` should be `@Override public boolean accept` or just leave it out so that it uses the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by providing a default implementation for `Base` as such;

```
// no need to annotate it with @service
class DefaultBase implements Base {

}
```

Then in your factory method,

```
private static final Base DEFAULT_BASE = new DefaultBase();

public void callingClass(String str) {
  Base base = baseList.stream()
      .filter(baseImpl -> baseImpl.accept(str))
      .findFirst()
      .orElseGet(DEFAULT_BASE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of service classes implementing your interface by autowiring.

Then, create a single default instance (it can be an anonymous class, or a named class as in atish's answer). It must not be a Spring service as you don't want it to be included in your autowired list. In your method, if no service class is found, return this default instance.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SomeService {
  private static final Base DEFAULT_BASE = new Base() {};

  @Autowired
  private List<Base> baseList;

  public void callingClass(String str) {

    Base base = baseList.stream()
        .filter(baseImpl -> baseImpl.accept(str))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(DEFAULT_BASE);

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way where I don't need to init DEFAULT_BASE?

Comment: @MohitKumar you can just use `.orElse(new Base() {});` but that would create a new instance of Base every time you call it, so it's highly recommended to initialize it and use that single instance.

Comment: but I don't want to create new Base() {} anywhere, can't we do it using Dependency injection?